# Vuex store API data integrity

Tags: vuex

I'm using Vuex to store external data from an API. This is data which can also be changed by others, so it might lead to a situation where I've stored outdated data. I'm looking for a way to somehow detect if the data has changed, so that I know if a new request should be made.

Is this possible with Vuex, or should I be looking at some other technique?

Comment: what you're looking for sounds like either server sent events or websockets; alternatively, you could use long polling too

Comment: but, if you've only got control over the front end, you may have some issues here since you have no real way of knowing the data has changed other than to actually pull it again